# Possible unhandled promise rejection react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In my dataloader the response I get I do this :

```
 method: 'PUT'
     })
    .then(response => response.json().then(json => {
       response.ok ? json : Promise.reject(json)}))
    .then(schematizeResponse)
```

On my Screen I have a button that dispatches the function and which is :

```
  _updateValues(){
  try{
   //update Email
    this.props.editProfile({
      currentUserToken: this.props.userSession.currentUserToken,
      data: {
        email: this.state.newEmail
      }
    })  
    this.state.updated= true;
  }
  catch(e) {
    this.state.updated= false;
  }
```

When the response fails, I get :

Possible unhandled promise rejection (id:0 ) and the response body.

The editProfile that I call through props is in my controller :

```
  function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
return {
  dispatch,
  editProfile: bindActionCreators(editProfileRequest, dispatch)
};
```

}

Update :

```
   this.props.editProfile({
      currentUserToken: this.props.userSession.currentUserToken,
      data: {
        email: this.state.newEmail
      }
    })
```

Here i need :

```
  try {
       this.props.editProfile({
      currentUserToken: this.props.userSession.currentUserToken,
      data: {
        email: this.state.newEmail
      }
    })  
  }
 catch( error ? )
{
this.setState({failedUpdate:true})
}
```

How do I handle the rejection ?

Answer (score 1):

You have the order wrong in your fetch. Try this:

```
method: 'PUT'
     })
    .then(response => {
     if (response.ok)
        return response.json()
     else throw new Error('error')
    .then(schematizeResponse).
     catch(err => alert(err));
```

Comment: Thank you but I also need to catch the error on the screen where I call the function that dispatches the action.
This way, if I remove the alert(err) I will still have unhandled promise rejection. Else it works. I do get the alert.
But I need to catch this error elsewhere so that I can change the state of a variable.

Comment: Then just reject your promise in the catch, should be the same

Comment: in the catch where you have put alert ?
Or in the catch where I have try and catch when calling the api ?
how ?
I'm sorry, I'm a beginner

Comment: It is fine, but I don't fully understand what you mean. Also, this.state is not the right way to update the fields. Check this.setState

Comment: Sorry, I updated the code.
I need to have this error accessible when on clicking on the update button that is connected to dispatching the action through mapDispatchToProp and then connect().
so when there is an error, I need to setState of a variable to true.